# Number of Edges in a convex polygon with n extreme points

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, convex-analysis

Will number of edges in convex polygon of n extreme points be n?

Here convex polygon means convex hull of finitely many points in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

An extreme point is point which can't be written as strict linear combinations of 2 points from polygon. And an edge of polygon is line segment such that if line joining two points from polygon $x$ and $y$ intersect that segment, then line segment contains line segment joining $x$ and $y$

Comment: Did you mean "...in $\mathbb R^2$"?

Comment: sorry. meant $R^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a closer look at the conditions mentioned by gerw.

Each edge is incident to two vertices.

This is the simple part: If there were three (or more) vertices, then one of them would be between the other two (Hilbert's axioms of order). This point would be a strict convex combination of the other two and as such it would not be a vertex.

Each vertex is incident to two edges.

Let $x_0$ be a vertex with three (or more) edges. Wolog $x_0=0.$ One edge connects $x_0$ with vertex $x_1,$ another edge connects $x_0$ with vertex $x_2,$ and yet another edge connects $x_0$ with vertex $x_3.$ As $x_0,$ $x_i$ and $x_j$ cannot be on the same line for $(i,j)\in\{(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)\},$ we can find $\lambda_1\neq 0,$ $\lambda_2\neq 0$ and $\lambda_3\neq 0$ such that
$$
\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\lambda_3x_3=0
$$
and $\lambda_i>0$ for at least two indices $i\in\{1,2,3\}.$

If $x_i=(u_i,v_i),$ we can use
$$
\lambda_1=\varepsilon \begin{vmatrix} u_2 & u_3  \\ v_2 & v_3\end{vmatrix}
\;\;,\;\;
\lambda_2=\varepsilon \begin{vmatrix} u_3 & u_1  \\ v_3 & v_1\end{vmatrix}
\;\;,\;\;
\lambda_3=\varepsilon \begin{vmatrix} u_1 & u_2  \\ v_1 & v_2\end{vmatrix}
$$
and choose $\varepsilon\in\{-1,1\}$ such that at least two elements in $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3\}$ are positive.

If $\lambda_1,$ $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ are all positive then 
$$
x_0 = 0 = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3}x_1
+\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3}x_2
+\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3}x_3
$$
which makes $x_0$ a strict convex combination of $x_1,$ $x_2$ and $x_3.$ This contradicts the fact that $x_0$ is a vertex.

If one of $\lambda_1,$ $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ is negative (wolog $\lambda_3<0$), then we can easily find a point $y_1$ on the edge $x_0x_1$ and a point $y_2$ on the edge $x_0x_2$ such that $y_1y_2$ intersects $x_0x_3$ which contradicts the fact that $x_0x_3$ is an edge:

Let 
$$
m=|\lambda_1|+|\lambda_2|+|\lambda_3|
\;,\;\; y_1 = \frac{\lambda_1}{m} \,x_1
\;,\;\; y_2 = \frac{\lambda_2}{m} \,x_2
$$
then
$$
\frac{1}{2}(y_1+y_2) = \frac{1}{2m}(\lambda_1 x_1+\lambda_2 x_2)
=\frac{-\lambda_3}{2m}\,x_3
$$
which means that the center of the line segment $y_1y_2$ lies on $x_0x_3.$

Comment: why the last part?

Comment: @Sushil I added the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the number of edges is $n$. This follows from:

- Each edge is incident to two vertices (independent of the dimension)
- Each vertex is incident to two edges (only for dimension two)

Comment: why each vertex indcident to 2 edges only?

Comment: Can you draw a polygon having a vertex with more than 2 edges?

Comment: I think this is a challange rather than an answer. :-)

Comment: I accepte your answer because after looking your answer, searching for it make mw look for concept of dual polytope and a general theorem that no. of facet in any polytope is equal to no. of edges.

Comment: @Sushil I thought you wanted an answer that depends on the given definitions of "convex polygon", "edge" and "vertex", only. In my opinion, you skip a lot of non-trivial proof steps if you apply the concept of dual polytopes to the original problem.